# Не применяется padding, элемент выходит за пределы контейнера, размеры шрифтов не совпадают с макетом

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

мне нужна помощь понять один момент, при просмотре макета в Zeplin, размер шрифта, допустим, указан 41px, а его высота height равна при этом 44px[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в самой верстке эта высота при таком же размере шрифта почему-то уже является 49px, вследствие чего не все элементы влезают в контейнер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же еще более важным вопросом встает то что внутренний нижний отступ padding в классе .promo почему то не применился на вложенные элементы контейнера, а верхний да, например иконка скролла не влезла, но что-то мне подсказывает, это из-за высоты шрифтов

**как должно быть**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**как получилось**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на макет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWa8fFoUF1F89x0xHjbTA4boZVenHyJy/view?usp=sharing)

**Код**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.promo {
    height: 800px;
    background: url('../img/bg01.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
    padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

.simple {
    margin-top: 21px;
}

.title {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f9bf3b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.simple .title_big {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 21px;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 53px; 
}

h2.title {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.promo .promo_text {
    padding: 0 13px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1.33;
}

.promo .promo_text span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f9bf3b;
}

.promo .promo_btn {
    width: 313px;
    height: 72px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border: solid 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #2798b9, #3ab6da);
    display: block;
    margin: 73px auto 73px;
    text-shadow: -0.7px -0.7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    line-height: 1.14;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.more {
    
}

.more .more_text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.more .more_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="promo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./logo/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
                <div class="logo_text">
                    Wordpress интенсив
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress 
            </h1>
            <div class="simple">
                <h2 class="title_big">это просто!</h2>
                <div class="line">    
                </div>
            </div>   
            <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>
            <div class="promo_text">
                Ежедневно в России появляется более 5 000 новых сайтов.<br>И только единицы из них становятся популярными и приносят ощутимую прибыль. В чем секрет? В чем формула успеха? Узнайте на предстоящем двухдневном <span>БЕСПЛАТНОМ</span> интенсиве!
            </div>
            <button class="promo_btn">Записаться на интенсив</button>
            <div class="more">
                <div class="more_text">
                    узнать больше об интенсиве
                </div>
                <img src="./icons/bottom.svg" alt="bottom" class="more_img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="trigger">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="trigger_header">
                Что вас ждет в нашем интенсиве?
            </h2>
            <div class="trigger_line">

            </div>
            <div class="trigger_subheader">
                2 бесплатных полноценных обучающих вебинара, где:
            </div>

            <div class="trigger_wrapper">
                <div class="trigger_item">
                    <img src="./img/img1.png" alt="img1" class="trigger_img">
                    <div class="trigger_descr">
                        Всего за два бесплатных вебинара мы научим вас, как создать свой сайт на WordPress. 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="trigger_item">
                    <img src="./img/img2.png" alt="img2" class="trigger_img">
                    <div class="trigger_descr">
                        Покажем, как правильно оптимизировать сайт и сделать его привлекательным для поисковых систем. Только свежая, профессиональная и актуальная информация!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="trigger_item">
                    <img src="./img/img3.png" alt="img3" class="trigger_img">
                    <div class="trigger_descr">
                        Вы узнаете, что такое «хорошая индексация», «высокая посещаемость», «стабильный прирост посетителей», «ТОП по запросам» и, что намного важнее, как добиться всех этих показателей!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Масштаб в браузере сбрось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> в самой верстке эта высота при таком же размере шрифта почему-то уже
> является 49px

Потому что не задан line-height. Он берется из браузера, где по дефолту что-нибудь вроде 1.2em стоит.

> отступ padding в классе .promo почему то не применился на вложенные элементы контейнера

Паддинги не наследуются.

Answer (score 0):

В

```
.promo {
    height: 800px;
}
```

надо поменять на

```
min-height: 800px;
```